# Pygame camera module not recognised

Tags: python-2.7, camera, pygame

I have been trying to play about with the pygame camera module, but can't get it to initialize. I have tried the code I seem to find popping up a lot in forums to get things started:

```
import pygame
import pygame.camera
pygame.init()
pygame.camera.init()
```

At this point I get a message saying:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pygame/camera.py", line 42, in init
    import _camera
ImportError: No module named _camera
```

I've also checked whether the pygame.camera module actually exists, using dir(pygame). It doesn't appear in the list. Any ideas? (using python 2.7.6 with pygame 1.9.2pre on OS X 10.9.2)

Comment: May i know what version of python you are using (e.g. python 2.7.4) as well as the OS you are currently using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the fact that you are using a unsupported OS. On the docs for the `pygame.camera` module, it says that only Linux and v412 cameras are supported. You can find some other modules that might work for your needs [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=camera&submit=search).

Hope this helped.